# Parse a pdf file and store data into database using grails

Tags: web-applications, grails

We have an URL by which we can download pdf file. 
Issues is that we have a input text field where we give URL and we have a submit button. if we click on submit button then download the relevant file and parse and stored in database.

Comment: Duplicate of deleted or already answered question.

Answer (score 3):

**Domain class**:

```
class Data {  
    byte[] pdfFile  

    static mapping = {  
        pdfFile sqlType:'longblob'      //use mysql  
    }  

    static constraints = {  
        pdfFile nullable:true  
    }  
}
```

gsp view to submit the url to controller, namely **getFile.gsp** for instance:

```
<g:form url="[action:'savePdf',controller:'data']" >  
       <g:textField name="externalUrl" >  
       <g:submitButton name="submit" value="Submit" />  
</g:form>
```

**DataController**:

```
class DataController {
    def savePdf() {                                  //save pdf file into database  
        def url = params.externalUrl           // for example:'http://moodle.njit.edu/tutorials/downloading_moodle.pdf' 

        def localFile = new FileOutputStream('test.pdf')  
        localFile << new URL(url).openStream()  
        localFile.close()  

        def pdfFile = new FileInputStream('test.pdf')  
        byte[] buf = new byte [102400]  
        byte[] pdfData = new byte[10240000]              //pdf file size limited to 10M  
        int len = pdfFile.read(buf, 0, 102400)  
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()  
        while(len > 0) {  
            bytestream.write(buf, 0, len)  
            len =pdfFile.read(buf, 0, 102400)  
        }  
        data.pdfFile = bytestream.toByteArray()  
        data.save()  
    }  

    def renderPdf() {                              //for pdf file download  
        def dataInstance = Data.get(params.id)  
        response.setContentType('application/pdf')  
        byte[] pdf = dataInstance?.pdfFile  
        response.outputStream << pdf  
    }  
}
```

To trigger renderPdf() method, put a link in another gsp view, let's say **render.gsp**:

```
<a href="${createLink(uri:'/data/renderPdf/'+dataInstance.id)}">pdf file</a>
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for reply, u told me about only how pdf store into database. i want to store only content of pdf into data base... assume that data in pdf like a table format

Comment: Well, that could be a whole project. I don't expect any answer about such a big topic here.

Comment: hey, may u give some idea.. how to solve this problem.. what should i use.. which library ??

Comment: I don't know. It depends on the structure of your pdf file and your database. If the pdf file consists of some data that is not structured, you may need to do some Natural Language Processing(NLP) work, which is quite tough.